# insert Delta between to xmls to table- SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have 2 xmls Like (the tags are Dynamic):

```
Declare @OldXml xml = <Data><testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId><description>Test1</description><Name>aaaa</Name><createdBy>1111</createdBy><updatedBy>1111</updatedBy></Data>

Declare @NewXml xml = '<Data><testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId><description>Test2</description><Name>bbbb</Name><createdBy>1111</createdBy><updatedBy>2222</updatedBy></Data>'
```

I want to enter the difference between them to another table like that:

```
  entity                                        Field              OldValue      NewValue  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2        description           Test1         Test2  
  BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2           Name                aaaa          bbbb
```

How can I do that?

Hi ,After a long search,I've found the answer

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    foo.bar.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)') as FieldName,  
    foo.bar.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')  as OldValue ,
    foo1.bar1.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')  as NewValue ,
    FROM
    @OldXml.nodes('/Data/*') AS foo(bar) 
    INNER JOIN @NewXml.nodes('/Data/*') AS foo1(bar1) ON foo.bar.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)') = foo1.bar1.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)')
                                                                                                        AND foo.bar.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)') <> foo1.bar1.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')
```

The Entity I'll get separately.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4178)

```sql
declare @OldXml xml = '
<Data>
  <testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId>
  <description>Test1</description>
  <Name>aaaa</Name>
  <createdBy>1111</createdBy>
  <updatedBy>1111</updatedBy>
</Data>
'
declare @NewXml XML = '
<Data>
  <testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId>
  <description>Test2</description>
  <Name>bbbb</Name>
  <createdBy>1111</createdBy>
  <updatedBy>2222</updatedBy>
</Data>'

select @OldXml.value('(Data/testId/text())[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') as entity,
       T.Field,
       @OldXml.value('(/Data/*[local-name(.) = sql:column("T.Field")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as OldValue,
       @NewXml.value('(/Data/*[local-name(.) = sql:column("T.Field")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NewValue
from (
     select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Field
     from @OldXml.nodes('/Data/*') as T(X)
     ) as T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4178/0)**:

```
|                               ENTITY |       FIELD |                             OLDVALUE |                             NEWVALUE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 |      testId | BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 | BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 |
| BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 | description |                                Test1 |                                Test2 |
| BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 |        Name |                                 aaaa |                                 bbbb |
| BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 |   createdBy |                                 1111 |                                 1111 |
| BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2 |   updatedBy |                                 1111 |                                 2222 |
```

Comment: Hi After a long search 

    SELECT DISTINCT
    foo.bar.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)') as FieldName,  
    foo.bar.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')  as OldValue ,
    foo1.bar1.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')  as NewValue ,
    FROM
    @OldXml.nodes('/Data/*') AS foo(bar) 
    INNER JOIN @NewXml.nodes('/Data/*') AS foo1(bar1) ON foo.bar.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)') = foo1.bar1.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(14)')
                             AND foo.bar.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)') <> foo1.bar1.value('./.','VARCHAR(14)')

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @OldXml XML = '<Data><testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId><description>Test1</description><Name>aaaa</Name><createdBy>1111</createdBy><updatedBy>1111</updatedBy></Data>'
    , @NewXml XML = '<Data><testId>BE7F2CDE-0D31-4E47-AA07-CE179F1E47C2</testId><description>Test2</description><Name>bbbb</Name><createdBy>1111</createdBy><updatedBy>2222</updatedBy></Data>'

SELECT id = 'NEW'
      , testId = t.c.value('(./testId)[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER')
      , [description] = t.c.value('(./description)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
      , createdBy = t.c.value('(./createdBy)[1]', 'INT')
      , updatedBy = t.c.value('(./updatedBy)[1]', 'INT')
FROM @NewXml.nodes('/Data') t(c)

UNION ALL

SELECT id = 'OLD'
    , t.c.value('(./testId)[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER')
    , t.c.value('(./description)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
    , t.c.value('(./createdBy)[1]', 'INT')
    , t.c.value('(./updatedBy)[1]', 'INT')
FROM @OldXml.nodes('/Data') t(c)
```